# Stuck with server.use()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im stuck with server.use is node.js. everytime i take `server.use(express.static('public'));` before `server.get` , it won't run, then i change `server.use(express.static('public'));` after `server.get()` it working well like nothing happened.

can someone tell me what is the difference ?

here my script :

```
    // Depedencies / built-in
import express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import nodeSass from 'node-sass-middleware';

// you can place anything here, except depedencies
import config from './config';
import apiRouter from './api/index';

const server = express();

// Including Middleware
server.use(nodeSass({
    src: join(__dirname + 'sass'),
    dest: join(__dirname + 'public'),
}));

// everytime i take this before Router, it running, but
// but, the index won't showing up
server.use(express.static('public'));

// Setting up view engine
server.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Router
server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        title: 'Hello EJs',
    });
});

// if i change after Route, it working well
// server.use(express.static('public'));

server.listen(config.port, () => {
    console.log('magic happen on port: ', config.port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer, by guesing what's wrong.

1) `server.use(express.static('public'));` This is just the way to tell your application where to look for static files like JS, CSS, images and other content that page will need to load. More info here . http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static

2) When you use `res.render('pathToRenderFile')` It will try to find file name with specified engine `server.set('view engine', 'ejs');` . If no engine is set you will need to add extension too. By default it will look in `views` directory. More info here http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

So in your case you need to put `index.ejs` inside `views/index.ejs`. Then all should work.

3) All of the middleware(middleware functions) like `server.use` or `server.set` should be set up before routes.

4) About middleware, and the point of it. Before or after any route you can perform some actions that you may require on request or response objects. For example you need this middleware https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser to have all post data inside req.body object. If you dont include it you will have to parse it yourself. That's why express gives you a good way to handle this cases, using build in or yourown middlewares.

Here is the list of all usefull middlewares https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware.html

Middleware functions are executed sequentially, therefore the order of middleware inclusion is important.

There is a good examples here https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll write this to my note.

Comment: i have to create index.ejs inside views directory, but nothing changed

Umm.. like i said, if i take `server.use(express.static('public'))` before Route it will working well like nothing happened. i just dont know how to take `server.use(express.static('public'))` and what is the difference if i take on top or bottom

Comment: Did you try like this `server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))`  ?

Comment: And what version of node / express you using?

Comment: I update my answer a little bit. Plus i tested your code in my PC..All works ok..So can you please tell what error you see?

Comment: #sorry for slow response.
i try `server.use(__dirname + '/public')` with no error, the code is running, but the index won't to show.

Comment: Okay..When you go to localhost/ what you see? empty page? or page wont load? if empty..then check console maybe you have some errors there. If it wont load then you should see errors in server logs..Somewhere should be warning.

Comment: sir.. do you know what is the problem ? my node version.. oh god.. 4 hrs i looking for a clue for my problem.. thanks for your reply
`And what version of node / express you using?`
you save my life

Comment: Np..Glad to help